# Can Delphi 5 use a C# .Net Library?

Tags: c#, delphi, ssl, dll, ldap

I am updating a legacy Delphi 5 application (that we have code for) that authenticates against LDAP/AD by binding using user-provided credentials.  However, the libraries we're using cannot work to bind against LDAPS (LDAP/SSL) over ports 636 or 3269.

I see that authenticating against LDAP/AD in C# can be as simple as:

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "testnet.testad.org:636", "dc=testnet,dc=testad,dc=org");
bool validated = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
```

I am thinking of wrapping the necessary calls in a .DLL, then invoking the call from within the Delphi app.  However, I'm presuming that there is a minefield of 'gotchas' that would prevent it from being this easy.

Comment: This can work, but only if the C# DLL exposes a flat C interface, or a COM server.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, whenever I see an answer from you, I know I am on a good path (or you'll put me on one.)  I'll start searching for how to create a C# COM Server in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: The easiest way IMHO is to use [UnmanagedExports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) to create a library in C# that exports a function which returns an interface. Works like a charm, requiring only a minimum of glue code.

Comment: @mghie, tried using UnmanagedExports, but encountering errors that are non-intuitive to resolve.  I'll keep that in my back-pocket, but will try to see if I can create a dll as per Remy's ideas first.  I think this will leave me in a better state to understand what is going on behind the scenes, especially as this should be both simple and tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [UnmanagedExports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) this is really quite easy.

You start with an interface for the functionality, like so:

```pascal
type
  IManagedInterface = interface
    ['{9F5A2431-5559-410C-BAB4-5144CA8C0B7B}']
    function CheckCredentials(AContextName, AContainerName, AUserName,
      APassword: WideString): integer; safecall;
  end;
```

This is probably not the best choice of parameter types, as you can't call that with `NULL` for user and password, and you would probably want to pass the other parameters (like context type) as well, but you get the idea.

Then you create a new Class Library (.NET Framework) project in VS 2019, setting the build target to x86 (for it to be compatible with Delphi 5). You add the NuGet package for UnmanagedExports.

Within that project you add the same interface:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("9F5A2431-5559-410C-BAB4-5144CA8C0B7B")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IManagedInterface
{
    int CheckCredentials(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string contextname,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string container,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string username,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string password);
}
```

and a class which implements that interface:

```
public class Class1 : IManagedInterface
{
    public int CheckCredentials(string contextname, string container,
        string username, string password)
    {
        var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, contextname, container);
        return Convert.ToInt32(pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password,
            ContextOptions.Negotiate));
    }
}
```

Finally you export a function from the DLL that creates and returns an instance of this class:

```
static class Exports
{
    [DllExport]
    public static void CreateTheInterface(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IManagedInterface instance)
    {
        instance = new Class1();
    }
}
```

Now you can use that DLL from Delphi (to keep this short the library is not loaded on demand, which I would do in production code):

```
procedure CreateTheInterface(out AInstance: IManagedInterface); stdcall;
  external 'ClassLibrary1.dll';

var
  Imi: IManagedInterface;
  context, container, username, password: string;
begin
  CreateTheInterface(Imi);

  if Imi <> nil then try
    context := 'testnet.testad.org:636';
    container := 'dc=testnet,dc=testad,dc=org';
    username := 'someguy';
    password := 'password';

    Writeln('call returned: ',
      Imi.CheckCredentials(context, container, username, password));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

So, no minefield of 'gotchas' and it is really quite easy.

Comment: Any idea what may be wrong if I get the error on build: "Provided key file 'G:\C#\LDAPAuth\LDAPAuth\Mono.Cecil.CustomAttributeArgument' cannot be found" ?

Comment: @DanielBragg: Maybe https://github.com/3F/DllExport/issues/48 does help? You don't need any COM stuff for above code.

Comment: It looks like signing the assembly was what was required.

Comment: @DanielBragg: Maybe it was in your case, but the steps as outlined in my answer (starting from scratch with a new library project) worked for me. Adding signing afterwards worked for me too. But I assumed you might have modified an existing library, hence my comment about COM stuff.

Comment: I had been using Properties -> Build -> Register for COM interop, but things got simpler when I removed that.  The code compiles now, and it _almost_ works.  What settings should I be using for PrincipalContext and ValidateCredentials in order to validate against ports 636 or 3269?

Comment: Additionally, is there a recommended implementation of `PrincipalContext` and `ValidateCredentials` that will permit an attempt against LDAPS first, and failing that, against simple binding LDAP?  We have clients that are in the process of making the secure change-over, and we would like to have one solution that can address both states.

Comment: @DanielBragg: Thanks for accepting this answer. I have used the exact code against AD using port 636 (with the proper name of the primary domain controller and distinguished name, of course), worked just fine. Maybe you have to repeat the call using different parameters on failure? But that's outside the scope of this question. Stack Overflow should provide plenty of help, within the "active-directory" or "principalcontext" tags for example.

Comment: Odd.  I'm cycling through a combination of options (SecureSocketLayer, no options [which is Negotiate+Signing+Sealing], Negotiate and lastly SimpleBind) and the only one that is working is SimpleBind, and only against port 389.  I have other code that is connecting to the server on port 636, so I know that is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231381/discussion-between-mghie-and-daniel-bragg).